# Tag modifications request

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-deletion, tag-synonyms

I found some of the tags which I think could be repaired or made synonyms. They are as follows:

1. [soul](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soul) - [jiva](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jiva) - [aatma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aatma) -  [spirits](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spirits) (*synonyms?*)
2. [puja](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puja) - [worship](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worship) (*synonyms?*)
3. [tantrik-vidhya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tantrik-vidhya) - [black-magic](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-magic) (*synonyms?*)
4. [sarasawati](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sarasawati) (*rename it to "Saraswati"*)
5. [sati-goddess](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sati-goddess) (*rename it to "Sati"*)
6. [beef](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beef) (*seems like unnecessary tag*)
7. [pork](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pork) (*seems like unnecessary tag*)
8. [ancient-india](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancient-india) - [india](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india) - [history](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) (*using history and india we can specify it as ancient india, IMO*)

Comment: I am waiting for a pro user to answer this question so that I can take necessary actions, about the tags **beef** and **pork** are now removed from the questions and are added as synonym to tag **food**. Wait for 24 hour cron job to remove these two tags from the system.

Comment: I've also renamed the tag of **sarsawati** to **saraswati**, this was really helpful, thanks

Comment: I think the reason the tag is "sati-goddess", is to distinguish it from Sati AKA Sahamarana, the practice of widows jumping into funeral pyres.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I would request you to sort this out so that I can get a clear picture for the synonym - renaming - retagging etc... cuz I can rely on you and jabahar for such things..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me go through them one by one:

- [soul](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soul) - [jiva](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jiva) - [aatma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aatma) -  [spirits](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spirits) - First of all we should spell the tag as atma rather than aatma, because that's the standard transliteration of the Sanskrit word.  Also, atma is just the Sanskrit word for soul, so I certainly agree that we should make soul a tag synonym for the tag [atma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atma).  Now I don't think we should make [jiva](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jiva) and [atma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atma) synonymous, because at a can refer to both jivatmas (the souls of humans) and Paramatma (divine soul or supersoul).  So if a user is asking about the discussion if the Atman in some Upanishad, they might be referring to Paramatma.  As far as [spirits](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spirits) goes, the only question with that tag is a question asking about whether Hindus believe in ghosts, so I think it's a fairly useless tag.  We might want to just remove the tag from that question, possibly replacing it with [ghosts](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghosts).
- [puja](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puja) - [worship](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worship) - Puja and worship are definitely not synonyms.  A puja is a very specific ritual used to worship the gods.  Not all worship of the gods is called puja.
- [tantrik-vidhya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tantrik-vidhya) - [black-magic](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-magic) - No, these aren't synonymous.  First of all, we might want to replace [tantrik-vidhya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tantrik-vidhya) with simply [tantra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tantra).  Second of all, tantra is neither a necessary nor sufficient condition for something to be black magic.  And I'm not sure we need a [black-magic](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-magic) in the first place; a [magic](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic) would probably suffice.  If we get so many questions about magic that we need to start distinguishing between light magic and black magic, then maybe we can create a tag at that point.
- [sati-goddess](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sati-goddess) - I think the reason the tag has the word goddess is to distinguish it from Sati AKA Sahamarana, the practice of widows jumping into funeral pyres. So it may be better to keep it as is.
- [ancient-india](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancient-india) - [india](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india) - [history](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) - Yes, the [ancient-india](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancient-india) is probably unnecessary.  If we're talking about Indian history, it's unlikely that we would be talking about how India got its Independence.  Typically we'd be talking about India in the time periods described in our scriptures.  The only reluctance I have about removing this tag is, what about questions about ancient India that don't involve historical scholarship, like questions about how much of ancient India King Bharata controlled according to scripture?  But the [india](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india) would probably suffice for that.

Comment: Now this is what I expect from other users as well... Great efforts

Answer (score 2):

Actions I've carried on for this particular post.

**Accepted Requests / Actions Taken**

- [beef](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beef) and [pork](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pork) are now *synonyms* of [food](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) - This solves the point **6** and **7**
- <s>[sarsawati](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sarsawati)</s> is now renamed to [saraswati](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saraswati) - This solves point **4**
- [aatma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aatma) is now renamed to [atma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atma), actually *Ātman* is a correct word but since thats not a general one, I will also add [atman](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atman) as synonym to [atma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atma) - Solves point **1** [partly]
- [soul](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soul) is now a synonym of [atma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atma) - Solves point **1** [partly]
- [spirits](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spirits) is now removed and [ghosts](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghosts) is added. - Solves point **1** [partly]
- [tantrik-vidya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tantrik-vidya) is now renamed to [tantra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tantra) and also, [tantrik-vidya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tantrik-vidya) is a synonym for [tantra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tantra) - This partly solves point **3**
- [ancient-india](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancient-india) is now removed and is replaced with [history](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history). Also, [ancient-india](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancient-india) is a synonym to [history](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) - This solves point **8** [partly]

**Rejected Requests / Invalid**

- [puja](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puja) and [worship](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worship) will be kept as separate tags as of now - This solves point **2**
- No change in the [sati-goddess](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sati-goddess) - This solves point **5**
- No change for [black-magic](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-magic) - This solves point **3** [partly]
- No change for [india](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india) - This solves point **8** [partly]