# The one tag cleanup post to rule them all

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I was going through our tags and I found some inconsistency and non-standardization and might need cleaning up. Few already raised and fix by  individual meta posts, and I did few by my own-self, which were quite [obvious ones](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) but I think we all can contribute to this tag standardization together.

Any tags that you feel need cleaning up over the main site or meta - post them as an answer, as they get voted up and down they can be cleaned up.

Users with more than 1250 reputation (on beta sites) and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

If you are confident about synonyms, you can suggest directly and get approval (given you have required score in that particular tag). If you are not so sure, you can suggest in answer  and this can be decided by votes.

Up vote = "I agree this tag need cleaning"

Down vote = "I disagree this tag needs cleaning"

No vote = What? No! Voting for the future, make your voice be heard!

I am presenting few from my opinion too and feel free to share your opinions as an answer but **only one tag issue per answer**.  Positive scorer/valid ones will be implemented ASAP.

---

To better understand the tag synonym and tag merging, refer:

[What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work)

---

<sub>**Inspired by and mostly copied by similar movies stack exchange [meta post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/the-one-tag-cleanup-post-to-rule-them-all)**</sub>

<sup>**Note**: You can try sorting answers by the [active tab](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/470/the-one-tag-cleanup-post-to-rule-them-all?answertab=active#tab-top) to see the more recent suggestions.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Make tag [papam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papam) a synonym of [sin](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin) or merge both. **Sin** is literal English translation of Sanskrit  word **papam**. Papam is there in many other languages too.

---

Update:

In Sanskrit, [pāpam](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?tinput=pApam&direction=SE&script=HK&link=yes&beginning=0) is an adverb whereas [pāpa](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?tinput=pApa&direction=SE&script=HK&link=yes&beginning=0) is a noun. We should try to use nouns as tag names.

Creating tag synonyms for all 3: [sin](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin), [papa](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papa) & [papam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papam) is more appropriate.

Similarly, we should rename current tag [punyam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punyam) (adverb) to [punya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punya) ([noun](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?script=HK&beginning=0%20&tinput=punya&trans=Translate&direction=SE))

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Merge the two tags one [weapon](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapon) and another [weapons](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons). It's just singular and plural. It doesn't have any meaning at all [astra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astra) can be made synonym after merging.

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Need to merge the two tags [parvati](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parvati) and [parvathi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parvathi). Tag [parvati](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parvati) is correct...

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Make the tag [tulasi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tulasi) a synonym of [tulsi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tulsi).

It is called 'Tulasi' in Sanskrit and not 'Tulsi.'

Comment: What you can do is, edit [one of the Q's](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tulsi) and create a new tag `tulasi`, then change your above answer and request for a synonym instead. It's better than fixing the 9 Q's that use `tulsi`.

Comment: @sv. That is no needed at all. If everyone like this suggestion it can be implemented straight forward.

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Merge the tags [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) and [shastras](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shastras). Make Shastra tag a synonym of Scripture.

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Make [devotee](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devotee) and [devotion](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devotion) tag synonym of [bhakti](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bhakti).

Few question have both the tag and they both can be merged and still make sense.

Comment: I didn't know that we had either a devotion tag or a devotee tag. Perhaps both should be merged with bhakti.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan fair enough, updated the option

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Need to merge these two tags: [ram](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ram) and [rama](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rama)

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Hindu astrology = Jyotish. So, make tag [jyotisha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jyotisha) synonyms of [astrology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrology) which clearly says:

> The branch of knowledge that deals with study of planetary positions to calculate time and determine its auspiciousness, forecast events, predict future and so on.

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The tags [vashishta](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vashishta) and [vasishta](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vasishta) are synonyms

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

1. Clean up tag [bali](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bali) that's used in a question related to Indonesia and also an unrelated question re: [King Bali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahabali).
2. Also clean up (edit and replace) [all occurrences](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bvali%5D%20bali) of "Bali" from questions and answers where it actually refers to [Vāli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vali_(Ramayana)) from Ramayana ([vali](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vali)).

Comment: Removed bali tag from population question and bali/vali fixed in shared questions. For the king bali question , i am keeping the bali tag for now.

Answer (score 3):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

There are no tags related to the Yadava dynasty, Vasudeva and so on. And there are no related tags as well, like Dynasty (Suryavamsa, Chandravamsa) and related tags. I have used the tag [yadavas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yadavas) for [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11164/what-happened-to-vasudevas-and-his-brothers-horde-of-children), but it hasn't been created.

Comment: It hasn't been created.??? How? I can see that tag.

Comment: And tags are only crested when they are needed, there is no way to create them in advance

Comment: @AnkitSharma Okay So that means we can create a new tag when a relevant question is asked?

Comment: Surely, it should complete the length limit (25) and should be relevant. Even we can add tags to old questions too if they needed it.

Comment: You should probably suggest [tag help](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/675) because you created it / used it first.

Comment: @Surya I just edited [your question](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11164) and added the 'yadavas' tag. I think you were new user at the time and did not have enough reputation to add a new tag by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The tags [shakti](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shakti) and [shakthi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shakthi) are synonyms

Also, [devi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devi) might be merged into [shakti](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shakti), although I personally prefer using [devi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devi)

Comment: Use of tag [tag:shakthi] is too vague to start with. It is used for shakthi peetha too.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Okay, no tag wiki is defined for it causing confusion

Comment: You can fix if you want else i will look into it on weekend , as synonym is not a good solution till it's used correctly

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Either clean up tag [grahas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grahas) or make it synonyms of [navagraha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/navagraha).

Information: [Navagraha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navagraha) is the nine planets used in Jyotish i.e Hindu astrology. So, while talking about planet/graha according to Jyotish, [navagraha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/navagraha) is more accurate. As [grahas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grahas) also convey same meaning, either tag [grahas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grahas) should be cleaned or make synonyms of [navagraha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/navagraha).

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Merge [yajna](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yajna) and [yagna](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yagna) as they are synonyms.

Tag [yajna](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yajna) is clearly defined:

> yajña, yagna, or yagya (Sanksrit: यज्ञ, "worship, prayer, praise; offering, oblation, sacrifice; fire ceremony") comes from the root yaj, "to worship" — is an outer form of worship in which offerings are made to different deities in a prescribed and systematic manner by qualified priests to supplicate them, so that they would assist the worshiper in achieving certain results in life.

Make [yagna](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yagna) synonyms of [yajna](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yajna).

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Merge [temple](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/temple) and [temples](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/temples) which stand for same-thing. `temples` is the plural of `temple`.

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Make [sages](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sages) synonyms of [rishi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rishi).

We've already clearly [defined](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tags/rishi/info) tag for Rishi:

> rishi (Sanskrit: "seer; one who sees") — is a word that simply means a **sage** or a divine seer in general.......

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Here are some synonyms.

- [vishnu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vishnu) and [narayana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narayana)
- [shiva-lingam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shiva-lingam) and [lingam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lingam)

Comment: It's better to give one suggestion per post, It will also help in getting clear community opinion/input.

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - literature tag fully removed.

Make [literature](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature) a synonyms of **[scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture)** which is very popular and useful tag (with 484 questions till now) for our community forever.

Comment: You can check with Keshav why he used both on one of his questions.

Comment: @sv. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33994108#33994108

Comment: I too think any more recent Sanskrit work from 1900's or any upcoming work should use the literature tag but not scripture. But we are not supposed to be asking Q's on literature here anyway, it has to have strong connection to scripture in some way.

Comment: I feel it's better to remove literature tag fully from all those questions. Rather then making them synonym.

Answer (score 2):

There is NO tag for [social-divisions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-divisions) or [varna-vyavastha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/varna-vyavastha). Preferably both should be added, but in merged way. The only one I see is [caste-system](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caste-system) which is grossly misunderstood representative of "divisions", as I have pointed in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9202/1049).
It's upto moderators' discretion, if the newly created tags should be separated from "caste" or merged with "caste" or remove anyone of them.

Comment: It do look like a problem as we are getting new tags in this umbrella, will try to come up with something soon.

Answer (score 2):

Copied from @Dharmaputhiran's question [My concern about the use of mythology tag](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/352/2995):

> One of [my question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/4107/81) has been edited and tagged under
>   **[mythology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology)**. The question was about Mahabharata and Hindus believe
>   that Mahabharata is not a myth but an authentic history. Myth and
>   history are contradictory.
>
> Of course, I know that there are two meanings for the word myth: (1):
>   a traditional story (2): a widely held but false belief or idea.
>
> There was a [similar question](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/290/81) here. Keshav, in his answer there,
>   has stated that the tag is being used in the meaning of a **traditional**
>   **story**. But the word **myth** is now widely being used in the context of
>   a **false idea**. That would naturally cause confusion to a normal user,
>   especially to the new ones.
>
> Actually, even I was taken aback when I first saw my question tagged
>   under mythology. **So, what if we have a separate tag to be used with
>   questions about ancient Hindu history?**

Comment: @Dharmaputhiran If normal users end up using the tag incorrectly, then we need to educate them. We can however create a synonym on 'mythology' tag called 'traditional-story' if you want.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I created a new tag **[ashvatthama](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ashvatthama)** and suggested tag help.

Need to search for all relevant questions and apply the new tag (if there's tag-space left on the questions)

But I also see people using names that are spelled slightly differently: **Ashwatthama** and **Ashwatthaman** so it's better to create synonyms to account for them.

Comment: Ashwatthama seems more popular, so i have kept it primary and made other its synonym

Comment: Could be, I just used the spelling from [sacred-texts.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Awww.sacred-texts.com%2Fhin+ashvatthama&oq=site%3Awww.sacred-texts.com%2Fhin+ashvatthama&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.378j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Only two question needed the tag, one is even duplicate. Anyways added in them too.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Ok, great.

Answer (score 2):

Someone created a new tag [sannyasa](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sannyasa) when there's already a [sanyasi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sanyasi) tag.

Need to merge both. Also, if there's a way, we should create another tag [sannyasi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sannyasi) (double 'n') so we're covered if someone creates it and uses on a new question.

Comment: sannyasa is a spelling mistake. If that tag is not used for some time, it gets deleted and we can create [tag:sanyasa].

Comment: @SreeCharan Wiki uses '[Sannyasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sannyasa)'. Also, see [here](https://www.vedabase.com/en/search/site/sannyasa?f[0]=im_vb_book_parent%3A2600).

Comment: In telugu we write సన్యాసం. In sanskrit we write सन्यास. In which system it is sannyasa? IAST or ITRANS?

Comment: @SreeCharan Yes, there seems to be some confusion. See [Monier Williams dictionary](http://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/cgi-bin/monier/serveimg.pl?file=/scans/MWScan/MWScanjpg/mw1148-saMnyas.jpg). They use संन्यास ... (saMnyAsa in Kyoto)

Answer (score 2):

Make [verse](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verse) a synonyms of [sloka](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sloka)

Answer (score 2):

Make [hymn](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hymn) a synonyms of [stotra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stotra)

Answer (score 2):

I introduced two news tags [brahmachari](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brahmachari) and [brahmacharya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brahmacharya)

Let's merge both these using synonyms .

Comment: brahmachari - celibate  brahmacharya - celibacy. It is like Hindu and Hinduism

Comment: @SreeCharan Ok. Are you saying we need 2 tags one for noun and other for adjective? I made a similar tag request [here](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/726/2995) - sannyasa and sannyasi.

Comment: I have seen that too. If you ask to merge them, I am gonna stay silent. Let the community decide. Synonym also looks fine.

Comment: @SreeCharan Ok. I was just trying to understand what you meant by your first comment as I already know the difference :)

Answer (score 1):

Make tag [shad-darshana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shad-darshana) synonyms of [philosophy](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy)

We've a popular tag [philosophy](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy) which stands for:

> Questions about Hindu Philosophy, which is divided into six main schools: Sankhya, Yoga, Nyaya, Vaiśeṣika, Mimamsa and Vedanta.

I've recently found a tag [shad-darshana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shad-darshana) where darshan means philosophy and shad means six. This is already included in tag [philosophy](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy). So, make [shad-darshana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shad-darshana) synonyms of [philosophy](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy).

Comment: Yes, synonym makes total sense here, upvoted.

Comment: I think "dharshana" should be philosophy rather than shad-darshana. Shad darshana refers only 6 schools of thought.

Comment: @TheDestroyer It looks like whoever first created 'philosophy' tag had 'shad-darshana' in mind. So this post is to merge both. For a specific philosophy we should use 'vedanta', 'vaiśeṣika' etc. A separate 'shad-darshana' don't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Need following synonyms for [bhagavata-purana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bhagavata-purana):

1. [srimad-bhagavatam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/srimad-bhagavatam)
2. [srimad-bhagavata](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/srimad-bhagavata)
3. [srimad-bhagavata-maha-purana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/srimad-bhagavata-maha-purana)
4. [bhagavata](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bhagavata)
5. [bhagavatam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bhagavatam)

Comment: Common practice should be to create tag synonym when it's really required. Creating them in advance when there is no confusion at all is bit far fetched practice.

Comment: @AnkitSharma This is a special case, you will rarely see people writing "Bhāgavata Purāṇa" in their questions and answers, most people write it as "Śrīmad Bhāgavataṃ" or just "Bhāgavataṃ". Maybe next time when I ask a question related to SB, I can start introducing these new tags!

Comment: @sv. Irrespective of what people writing in their posts, they're using `bhagavat-purana` tag.

Answer (score 1):

These two tags [gods](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gods) ([tag info](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tags/gods/info): 'For questions about Hindu gods in general') and  [devas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devas) ([tag info](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tags/devas/info): 'Gods in Vedic mythology, Hinduism') are similar. I think both words convey the same meaning. So need to merge into one. Most probably [devas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devas) is more significant in the context of Hinduism.

We also have [deities](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deities) defined as a synonym of [gods](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gods):

> [image]

So we have a lot of tags that convey the same meaning. Need to merge all these into one.

Comment: This makes sense. Not sure why people downvoted without leaving a comment.

Comment: @sv. dieties and gods are different. I think diety represents idol in temple.

Comment: @TheDestroyer For 'deity', my dictionary says: "Any supernatural being worshipped as controlling some part of the world or some aspect of life or who is the personification of a force" – no mention of idol there. So, deity = god = deva (all are same) ... idol = idol

Comment: @sv. Google says idol too. But Merriam webster says only Supernatural being.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I actually googled before posting my earlier comment. Google says "A god or goddess (in a polytheistic religion)." – no idol in there. I'm guessing it's the Indian English writers who messed it up using 'deity' to mean 'idol' and vice versa.

Comment: @sv. What is final conclusion?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Personally, I think `devas` (Sanskrit) and `gods` (English) are one & the same so best to make them synonyms, but there are 3 downvotes here. So leave it up to you. Re: deities & gods, they are already defined as synonyms, so there's nothing to fix there.

Comment: @sv. Dieties tag is merged with Gods. But there are two different tags Gods and Devas. I think Gods also should be merged with Devas (Master tag).

Answer (score 1):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

A new tag [ramayan](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ramayan) was introduced by way of [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16649).

We should either delete it or merge with existing tag [ramayana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ramayana)

Comment: You already removed it from the question, so tag will be deleted automatically after few days of no use. No way to delete it manually.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Ok, good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Make the [puja](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puja) synonym of [worship](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worship). Keeping [worship](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worship) as the master

In the tag excerpt of worship:

> It is widely referred to as *Pooja* in Hinduism.

Comment: How about keeping Puja as the master since it is Sanskrit term?

Comment: @Pandya This is english language based site. Keeping the english tag would help more people including users whose native is not India, Also I proposed to make [tag:papam] synonym of [tag:sin] but Ankit Sharma kept papam. I would also ask to change that one too.

Comment: The same request was [rejected](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/295/277) earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Tag name for Manusmriti should be [manusmriti](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manusmriti) not [manu-smriti](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manu-smriti), as it's always written as one word not two. If approved [manu-smriti](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manu-smriti) can become the synonym for the new tag.

Comment: Good suggestion. Out of curiosity, this post's Qn was started by you. Why your name is not appearing there and instead it's appearing as "anon"?

Comment: @iammilind I disassociated my account from the post as I am not a mod anymore and don't wish to get notification every time for new answer comes. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225997/182734

Answer (score 0):

This question - [How to start reading Bhagavad Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5404/how-to-start-reading-bhagavad-gita) - sounds like a personal advice question however the community has allowed it.

Since we've decided to allow it, how about a new tag for such questions? **[advice](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice)** or **[general-advice](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-advice)**?

Comment: Anyways I am also in favor of keeping this question as its more like a general advice to me rather then  personal advice but i am not sure of your tagging suggestion, will leave it to others for decision.

Comment: I think you should discuss this as separate meta question as this post is about cleaning up tags. Or you may also add new tag to relevant question.

Answer (score -1):

Make [symbols](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbols) a synonym of [symbolism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbolism)

Because [symbolism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbolism) is more appropriate, used more often and also has a clear [tag info](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tags/symbolism/info).

Comment: I remember in chat a while back there was a discussion that the word "symbol" has two meanings - it can either mean visual symbols like Om and the Swastika, or it can refer to symbolism like Ganesha's broken tusk symbolizing something. So if we merged symbol with symbolism we would lose the other meaning of the word symbol.  On the other hand, if we leave it the way it is then people may just randomly pick whether to use the symbol tag or the symbolism tag. So I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: I think we should merge both and make it easy. Let people pick whatever they want. Onus is on the reader to understand the context.

Answer (score -1):

Vote for whether [calendar](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar) and [panchang](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/panchang) are synonyms or not.

In other words (vote for) make [calendar](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar) a synonyms of [panchang](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/panchang)

Comment: panchānga is both a calendar and almanac - so don't think we should merge these two. Also, the correct tag name should be panchānga not panchang. We should prefer Sanskrit names here over Hindi. In the South it's called pañcāṅgam.

Answer (score -2):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Make [life-span](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/life-span) tag synonym of [life](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/life).

I don't think [life-span](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/life-span) should be treated as different tag and should be sub tag or synonym of [life](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/life) tag

Comment: I'm not sure why we have a life tag at all.  A life-span tag makes some sense, given life-spans in different Yugas.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan some of them need tag cleaning

Answer (score -2):

Add new tags: **[vegetarianism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetarianism)**, **[non-vegetarianism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-vegetarianism)** and **[vegan](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegan)**

Make them synonyms of each other.

Also make current tag **[non-vegetarian](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-vegetarian)** synonym of above or just rename it to **[non-vegetarianism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-vegetarianism)**

Use the following tag wiki for the unified tag:

> Use this tag for questions related to vegan, vegetarian or non-vegetarian food.

Use the following **full** tag wiki for the unified tag:

> - **Vegetarianism** is the practice of abstaining from the consumption of meat (red meat, poultry, seafood, insects and the flesh of any other animal), and may also include abstention from by-products of animal slaughter.
> - **Veganism** is both the practice of abstaining from the use of animal products, particularly in diet, and the philosophy that rejects the commodity status of animals. A follower of veganism is known as a **vegan**.
> - **Non-vegetarian**: One who is not a vegetarian!

EDIT:

Questions that currently use or should use one of the proposed tags from above:

- [Why can we eat 'living' plants but not 'living' animals?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/97/2995)
- [Why milk is considered to be OK food?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9273/2995)
- [Can we eat food before we visit a temple?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8302/2995)
- [Were Pandavas non-vegetarians?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9301/2995)
- [Brahmins used to eat Five-nailed animals?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8685/2995)
- [Why should we be vegetarian?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9799/2995)
- [Is cutting vegetables sin according to Sanatana dharma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3903/2995)

Comment: Instead of creating 3 tags, it's better to have single as **[tag:food-habits]**. There will be too less questions on each tag, if they are separated. But with combined, there will be sizable amount of questions.

Comment: Do we even have question on all three food habits? Seems bit unnecessary. iammilind's suggestion seems bit more reasonable.

Comment: @iammilind I think Food-habits is too generic. I'm not sure if many people think of that that tag to apply. The 3 tags I proposed will not be independent of each other, they will be synonyms so they all point to same tag. Looks like there's also a food tag: **[tag:food]**

Answer (score -2):

Need to merge these two tags: [gita](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gita) and [bhagavad-gita](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bhagavad-gita)

The second one is more widely used.

Comment: Although second one is widely used. But we have other Gitas as well like Vyasa Gita from Kurma Purana, Shiva Gita from Padma Purana, Rudra Gita from Varaha Purana, Ishwara Gita from Kurma Purana, Brahma Gita and Suta Gita from Skandha Purana, Anu Gita from Ashwamedha Parva, Avadhuta Gita, Devi Gita from Devi Bhagvatam, Uddhava Gita from Srimad Bhagvatam and so on many other Gitas. So I think we need both tags. One specially for the famous **Bhagvad Gita** and another **Gita** tag for all other Gitas.

Comment: @Tezz The way 'gita' tag is used right now, it's being used for Bhagavad Gita if you look at the questions. For other gita's, we need to use specific tag for those. Not sure how a generic one is useful - it will only cause confusion.

Comment: Then we can just merge them and then remove gita tag and let it die eventually. But for that I need to check all gita tags first

Comment: @AnkitSharma There are only 12 Q's with gita tag. Some users have used both on the same Qn not knowing which one is correct, maybe best to make 'gita' synonym of 'bhagavad-gita'.

Answer (score -3):

Separate tags for [shiva](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shiva) and [shankara](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shankara) (or mahadeva), as many people use them interchangeably.

Ref: [Are Lord Shiva and Lord Shankar two different deities?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2278/1049)

---

In my knowledge, Shiva is also said to be another name of [nirguna-brahman](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nirguna-brahman), hence having that tag as another synonym is desirable. Similar for [vishnu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vishnu) and [saguna-brahman](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saguna-brahman).
Above needs to be checked before proceeding.

Comment: I agree with your proposal of separate tags for Shiva and Shankara or Rudra. But not all people agree your 2nd proposal of Synonyms.

Answer (score -3):

Make [sanatanadharma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sanatanadharma) a  synonym of [dharma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dharma)

Comment: No. Dharma has different meanings. Sanatana Dharma is used for Hinduism but Dharma could mean Righteousness, duty, morality..

Answer (score -4):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Make [prayer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prayer) tag and [worship](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worship) tag synonym of [puja](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puja)

Comment: I did suspected that worship and prayer have different meaning and [foud this](http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-prayer-and-vs-worship/). Anyways thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I think we should combine worship and prayer, but that tag should be separate from puja.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan but as per all the link and definitions, worship and prayer are different things. http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-prayer-and-vs-worship/

Answer (score -4):

Tag [rashi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rashi) should be a synonym of [astrology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrology)