# We need a new post for tag cleanup

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-deletion, tag-synonyms

I think we need a new "tag cleanup post" because the existing one ([The one tag cleanup post to rule them all](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/470)) has grown very big (40 answers) and it's becoming difficult to get notifications or see a new answer listed in the active questions if the same user or multiple users post multiple answers on same day.

It looks like the original idea was for people to look at tag requests (delete, merge, rename etc) and vote on them. If people don't get to see a new answer because it's buried deep within the answers, how are they going to vote on it?

Or we should probably switch back to the old way i.e., separate questions for separate tags.

---

EDIT:

Got the following suggestion from comments below:

> Delete the answers for already resolved issues.

This might work, provided, the 'status-completed' answers are completely purged from the site. But if they keep showing up as 'deleted' - it serves no purpose as it's going to be a huge distraction at least for high-rep users who can see all these deleted posts.

E.g., here's how a deleted post looks to a high-rep user:

[image]

Comment: Maybe we should just trim down the thread by deleting the answers for already resolved issues.

Comment: Yes, that will work. Somehow we just need to make new answers more visible to others. But starting a new post is better, deleted answers still keep showing for high-rep users and is definitely a distraction.

Comment: I don't think it is needed at all.. we can just "order by active"... It makes active posts come in the first...

Comment: I always check them all and act when it's urgent.

Comment: @Tezz What if recently active ones are a bunch of 'status-closed' answers?

Comment: How about replacing/revising *your* status-completed answers with *your* new suggestions? /cc @AnkitSharma

Comment: @Pandya Not possible. What happens to the casted votes ?

Comment: @Pandya sound like a bad idea as the point of the post was to collect community conscious on the tagging decision by vote, I do ignore vots in obvious cases for sure.

Comment: @AnkitSharma oh! yes, I forgot to consider votes. /cc SreeCharan

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan there are rejected ones too and deleting them might make others asking it again too

Answer (score 4):

Well, since the activity of cleaning of tags has been being done by a moderator, it directly depends on who is handling this post. Here [Ankit Sharma](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/76/ankit-sharma) is nicely handling them and it [seems](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/765/we-need-a-new-post-for-tag-cleanup#comment2755_765) that he is not facing any trouble with it.

This is not a big issue that [The one tag cleanup post to rule them all](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/470/277) has many answers. SE can have a [question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140) with thousands of answers!

**You can always sort answers according to `active` tab:**

[image: screenshot]

So, visitors can view the recently added post with the help of using `active` tab and can cast vote. (You can find similar suggestion (of sorting answers by the active tab) at [this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3770/66803) meta post).

OK, such suggestion is added to [The one tag cleanup post to rule them all](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/470/277) as a note so-that it will be easy for visitors to get the more recent answers filtered by using the active tab.

The suggestion of deleting [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) answers doesn't look fine to me as it is meaningless for users with moderator privileges as well as it makes the entire post ugly.

Talking about switching back to the old way i.e separate questions for separate tags, I think we can implement it after graduation or when we've enough users with [Create Tag Synonyms](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) privilege considerably active for [Tag Synonyms](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms). So, I think the current [The one tag cleanup post to rule them all](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/470/277) is fine as of beta community.