# Tag Cleanup proposals

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Post a tag as answer which needs reworking (delete, merge, rename etc). I will fix simple issues of tag synonyms or renaming but some tag proposals can only be fixed by discussing with fellow users. So, votes on tag proposals will be used to fix them.

Up vote = "I agree this tag need cleaning"

Down vote = "I disagree this tag needs cleaning"

Also, don't forget to mention the reason in comments.

Actually, Users with more than 1250 reputation (on beta sites) and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

If you are confident about synonyms, you can suggest directly and get approval (given you have required score in that particular tag). If you are not so sure, you can suggest in answer and this can be decided by votes.

But i suggest you to post here the even simple tag cleanup proposals and i will fix these issues as soon as possible. Also, **post only one tag issue per answer**.

For more details on tag cleanup, visit Meta SE post: [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work)

Comment: Mods should lock those answers which are "[meta-tag:status-completed]". Because, after resolving, if such posts receive downvotes later, then Mods won't intend to undo the resolution act. If anyone has anything to say about such resolved answers, let them flag with their opinions for the Mod's attention.

Answer (score 7):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There is a [sloka](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sloka) which we are using for questions about couplets and verses. Recently, a similar tag [shloka](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shloka) was also created. They should be synonymized (perhaps merged). As we usually use 'sh' for the letter श , as in [shiva](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shiva), [shakti](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shakti) , [adi-shankaracharya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adi-shankaracharya) etc., latter tag can be selected as  master tag.

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[murti](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/murti) and [idols](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idols) should be synonyms as both stands for the similar or same meaning I think.

Comment: Agree. murti (as word idol has bad connotation) can be master tag.

Comment: Why is this still pending?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Which do you think should be a master tag?

Comment: Anything is fine to me.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma As idol is frequently used and also has a tag excerpt, it's kept as master and idol is now synonymous.

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

As we have a policy of using [Sanskrit names over other Hindi names](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229/spelling-non-english-words-in-english-search-results) in tags and answers, I propose to merge [rakshasa](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rakshasa) with newly created [rakshas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rakshas).

Answer (score 5):

We have [stotra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stotra) which is used for hymns on particular God/Goddess. There are only 4 questions with this tag.

We also have a [hymn](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hymn) for questions about hymns tagged for three questions. But there is no excerpt for that.

From [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hymn)

> Hymn: noun 
>   1.a song or ode in praise or honor of God, a deity, a nation, etc.

Stotra also has the same meaning.  From Monier-williams Sanskrit Dictionary,

> Stotra:   Stotra, am, n. praise, eulogium, a hymn of praise, ode. — Stotrārha (ºra-arº), as, ā, am, worthy of praise.

So, I feel these both tags should be made synonyms with hymn as master tag(As we are an [english language based site](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-are-the-allowed-languages-for-questions-comments-or-answers-here/57#57) and many can't understand sanskrit. We should keep the interests of all the users in mind).

I also request to add a tag wiki excerpt(and wiki if possible) for the tag so that the users may tag accurately.

Comment: I feel these both tags should be made synonyms...but...with **Stotra** as master tag...

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

We have [sanyasi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sanyasi) tagged for 17 questions. We also have an english equivalent [monks](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monks) for 2 questions.  We need to make monks synonym for sanyasi.

As sanyasi is more popular than monks, making sansyasi a master tag would be no problem.

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Make [gods](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gods) and [devas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devas) synonyms keeping gods as master tag. Because gods already have 2 synonyms.

Tag wiki excerpt for devas is :

> Gods in Vedic mythology, Hinduism.

Besides [deities](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deities) is already a synonyms of [gods](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gods).

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) : [close-voting](/questions/tagged/close-voting) will be remapped to [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close)

Meta tags: [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close) and [close-voting](/questions/tagged/close-voting) should be merged.

Comment: I was just thinking to propose it. [tag:vote-to-close] is one of the  default tags which every meta gets from its mother.

Comment: @Pandya vote-to-close is default tag inherited from Main meta. I think VTC should be master.

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[markandeya-puran](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/markandeya-puran) should be merged with [markandeya-purana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/markandeya-purana).

Answer (score 5):

[yudhisthira](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yudhisthira) should be renamed to [yudhishthira](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yudhishthira) ('s' -> 'sh').

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yudhishthira) uses "Yudhi**sh**thira." K M Ganguli also uses the same in his [translation](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01002.htm).

Comment: I support this proposal for consistency. Not only Wikipedia or K M Ganguli. We always use sh instead of a s while writing. We have Shiva, Vishnu, Adi Shankaracharya. This name is also popular and will show up in results.

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

We have [dronacharya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dronacharya) tagged for nine questions. We also have [drona](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drona) tagged for two questions. We need to make [drona](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drona) a synonym of [dronacharya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dronacharya) keeping Dronacharya as master tag.

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Although [yajnavalkya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yajnavalkya) is already a synonym of [yagnavalkya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yagnavalkya), it's not the primary tag name that shows up when you start typing 'yajna...'

> [image]

It's better to keep the most commonly used name (Wikipedia uses '[Yajnavalkya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yajnavalkya)') as the primary tag name.

So can we change 'Ya*j*navalkya' to be the primary tag name and 'Ya*g*navalkya' as the synonym/secondary tag?

Answer (score 2):

Meta tags [answers](/questions/tagged/answers) and [deleted-answers](/questions/tagged/deleted-answers) represents 2 different aspects and hence they should Not be synonyms. Both should be separate tags.

---

Also Mods should try to recover the past posts, which were originally tagged with [deleted-answers](/questions/tagged/deleted-answers).

Comment: In the mod view, you get a (x) next to the Tag synonyms. Once a mod clicks that, the posts which were originally tagged with the synonymized tag are automatically recovered.

Answer (score 2):

[anti-hindu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anti-hindu) [anti-sanatana-dharma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anti-sanatana-dharma) [pseudo-vedantism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pseudo-vedantism)

These 3 tags don't have any usage guidance or [tag wiki](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts) defined so not really sure on what questions should one use these. As [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) Help Center article says we usually create new tags for topics that are not already dealt with on the site:

> As a general rule, you should avoid creating new tags if possible, and new users are not allowed to create new tags. Even if you have sufficient reputation, you should only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question covers a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.

But in this case, it seems questions are asked just for the sake of tags.

If no one else is going to use these tags, let's delete them.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Corrected incorrectly typo from two questions. [ramyana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ramyana) will automatically removed by system as no question is associated with it now

Please synonymize [ramayana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ramayana) with [ramyana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ramyana).  (The second one is a typo, so we should keep the first one.)

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Please synonymize [kaliyug](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kaliyug) with [kali-yuga](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kali-yuga). ([kali-yuga](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kali-yuga) is far more popular.)

Answer (score 2):

Synonymize [devtas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devtas) with [devatas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devatas). ([devatas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devatas) is more popular.)

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Please synonymize [mahabharat](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mahabharat) with [mahabharata](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mahabharata). (It *is* [pending approval](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested), but that's gonna take *ages.*)

Answer (score 1):

We have [devi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devi) tagged for 84 questions.

> Devi is the feminine form of the Divine worshipped as Parvati, Lakshmi, Saraswati and many other forms. Also, known as Shakti.

Also [goddess](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goddess) for 93 questions.

> A female deity, e.g., Parvati, Lakshmi, Durga etc.

Deva means a God and [Devi](http://sanskritdictionary.com/dev%C4%AB/105554/1) means a [Goddess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devi) in Sanskrit. So, I think they should be synonymized to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Devi is also used to refer Adi Shakti. So, Goddess and Devi cannot be synonyms.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Where were you when I proposed the revision1 ? Pandya says they can't be synonyms. Then what to do with these ambiguous tags? Devi, Shakti, goddess?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma more tags means more fun :p

Answer (score 1):

Make [astronomy](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astronomy) synonyms of [astrology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrology).

I know that both stands for different meanings but I think [Jyotisha](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/551/277) includes both of them.

Answer (score 1):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

Since the word "mythology" has bad connotation as [explained here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1659/277), I suggest to

- #### Rename [mythology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology) to [sacred-stories](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sacred-stories) &
- #### Make [mythology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology) a synonyms of [sacred-stories](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sacred-stories)

Comment: Why is this discussion sidelined to an old and inactive post instead of already active detailed post? This is just a proposal whereas, the other post had different reasons why it should be or should not be removed. Changing without a reason looks like unidirectional. What happens to all the old discussions and sugesstions the community made past year?

Comment: This tag specifically should not be decided or modified just by votes because you know the reason. Votes on well written answers are reversed overnight and people are getting emotional rather than voting or editing based on content. There should be a discussion and not just votes.

Comment: -1, mythology tag discussion is a very broad one and need meta post of its own. I was always against mythology tag but  I never acted as I am not in support of dictatorship when I was mod and it should be properly discussed not like this. -2 for new name sacred-stories, which sound weirder.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Ok. By the way, can you post your views in answer to meta question om mythology tag ? Thanks

Comment: @Paṇḍyā which meta post, I mean I think we need a new one? and also I can't be making a full-fledged meta post anytime soon as my time is quite utilized but I will still try to do with comments and vote for sure

Comment: @AnkitSharma No, I meant giving feedback answer to [existing meta question](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1015/277). Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Make [saivism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saivism) (4 questions) a synonym of [shaivism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shaivism) (179 questions).

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Make [ganesh](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ganesh) a synonym of [ganesha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ganesha). Both are the exact same deity.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Make [kashi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kashi) a synonym of [varanasi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/varanasi).

Answer (score 0):

We should probably rename **[non-vegetarian](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-vegetarian)** to **[non-vegetarianism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-vegetarianism)**

Also, add new tags **[vegetarianism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetarianism)** and **[veganism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veganism)** and make all three synonyms of each other with **[vegetarianism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetarianism)** being the primary tag.

Answer (score -3):

Merge [reference-request](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) into [scriptures](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scriptures), or delete altogether as the it has very few posts. Both seem to mean the same.

Comment: We can directly delete reference request. Merging them into scripture will bring the issue back to square one. scripture used for references. But as you know, scriptures is for questions about scriptures and not about references.

Answer (score -4):

[vrata](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vrata) and [fasting](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fasting) can be made synonym keeping [vrata](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vrata) as master.

Comment: I think fasting is subset of Vrata. Vrata can also include piligrimages and other methods.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I think the tag wiki is not right. You may check meaning here: http://kjc-sv013.kjc.uni-heidelberg.de/dcs/index.php?contents=lemma&IDWord=116251

Comment: Yes. Vrata means religious vow and it can be anything. So, i think they are not exactly synonyms.

Comment: Ok. Then please let it not to do.

Comment: Same reason as given by TheDestroyer...

Answer (score -4):

[caste-system](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caste-system) should be replaced with [class-system](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/class-system) (or [division-system](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/division-system)).
It may also have a synonym as [varna-vyavastha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/varna-vyavastha) to cater the Sanskrit language.

There are only 4 classes or divisions named as: *Brahmana, Kshatriya, Vaishya, Shudra*. The classes are based on qualities.

There are/were/will numerous castes (*jaati*-s) and they may or may not relate to this classes directly. I have explained this concept in many answers. For example:

[What does Hindu scripture say about class hierarchy?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11240/1049)

Comment: There is already [tag:varna]. So, I think there's no need of Varna vyavastha.

Comment: @Sinister, I had already seen that. However, `varna` and `varna-vyavastha` are different terminologies. It's like `money` and `money-management`. A question on `varna` would hardly discussing the context of `varna-vyavastha` (i.e. the `class-system`) and vice versa.

Answer (score -4):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Make [prayer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prayer) a synonyms of [worship](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worship).

Comment: I disagree with this. [tag:prayer] is just a subset of [tag:worship], as prayer is a form of worship. There are many other forms of worship, most common of which are singing bhajans and doing keertans. (Satsang can also be considered a form of worship). They certainly aren't synonyms.

Comment: @BhargavRao Ok. And what about tag Puja?

Comment: That's tricky. Puja is actually worship, not prayer, but the prayer tag wiki tells that puja is prayer. I'm not that sure about it.

Answer (score -5):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Tag [satyanarayana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satyanarayana) should be made synonym to tag [vishnu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vishnu) with tag [vishnu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vishnu) as master tag.

Comment: Satyanarayana is a very specific form of Vishnu.  So it should be kept separate.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan If we allow tags for forms, then we have to allow Anuriddha, Pradyumna, Shankarshana also and Aghora, Sadyojata, Vamadeva, and so on..

Comment: Well, it's just a question of what things people are likely to ask about.  We aren't likely to get any questions about Vishnu's Vyuha form Pradyumna or Shiva's Sadyojyata form, but we are likely to get questions on Shiva's Nataraja form and Vishnu's Satyanarayana form.  So I think this tag is useful.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Ok. if we get more questions about Anirudda in future, should we allow Anirudda tag?

Comment: Yeah, in the unlikely event that people kept asking questions about Aniruddha, it would be fine to create a tag.